# Absolute position relative to an image

Tags: css, position, css-position

Is there a way to position an element relative to an `img` tag?

Of course I can make this image inside a div, and then position the element relative to this div. But let's say the image is already positioned, and i don't want to add other elements.

Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/MQf3D/

The blue div should go on the left top corner of the image (0px/0px)

**HTML**

```
<img class="im" /> 
<div class="di">Absolute</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.im {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 60px;
}

.di {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

Comment: Without using javascript you will have to wrap the two elements in another div tag.

Comment: You'll need another div...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually use the image's class as the parent div of the image and the text:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="im">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"> 
        <div class="di">Absolute</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MQf3D/2/

Comment: this will work so long as the img element is positioned relatively

Comment: also you should remove the 'outer' div as this is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: i did this but added `display=table` to `im` so if wrap the element close (have the same width of the picture) and work with `margin=0 auto`